# Is every local flat extension of a DVR a domain?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain, flatness

The title pretty much says it all.

I would like to know if it is true that given a finite flat ring extension $A \rightarrow B$ with $A$ a DVR, and $B$ a local ring, then $B$ is necessarily a domain. 
If it's not true, are there additional hypotesis on $B$ such that this is true?

Comment: What about something like $A[x]/(x^2)$?

Comment: sorry I forgot to say that $B$ should be a local ring too.

Comment: Is that not local? If $A$ has uniformizer $\pi$ then the unique maximal ideal of $A[x]/(x^2)$ is $(\pi,x)$. Indeed, if you have a maximal ideal then it must contain $x$ since $x$ is nilpotent. But, then you know that $\mathfrak{m}/(x)$ must be a maximal ideal of $A$ and so must be $\pi$ so that $\mathfrak{m}$ also contains $\pi$. So, $\mathfrak{m}\supseteq (\pi,x)$ but since this latter ideal is maximal as well they're equal.

Comment: OK yes you are right. Do you know of any condition I could add on $B$ for this to be true? For example if $B$ is unramified

Comment: If its unramified then it's true because then $B$ will be regular local, and regular local rings are domains.

Comment: Is the proof of this last fact trivial? Because right now I don't see how to prove it so I would like to know if you could give me a sketch of proof or a hint

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93008/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-gle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to get this off the unanswered list.

No, it is not true that if $B$ is a flat local $A$ algebra then $B$ is a domain. The example of $B=A[x]/(x^2)$ shows this. That said, if you demand that $B/A$ is unramified then this is true. Indeed, since $A\to B$ is both flat and unramified it's etale. This implies that since $A$ is regular local that so then is $B$ (e.g. see [Tag025N](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/025N)). But, regular local rings are domains (e.g. see [Tag00NP](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NP)).